# Print all svn revision of the days in Bash

Tags: bash, sh

I need to print all SVN revision of the day in a simple cycle but I am not able to parse them.

What I need is to cycle over the revision of each day. My problem is to obtain the revision date and the revision number in a script such as:

```
log=$(svn log -r {2011-11-01}:Head) 
startDate= #??? get first commit date from log
startCommit= #?? get first revision number from log

for $rev in $(log); do
#  revisionDate=??? (similar to startdate)   
#  revisionNumber=??? (similar to start commit)

   if [! $startDate = $revisionDate ]; then      
     echo $revisionDate
     echo $revisionNumber
   fi
done
```

This is the example of a svn log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1619603 | aw | 2014-08-21 23:33:35 +0200 (Thu, 21 Aug 2014) | 2 lines

YARN-2436. [post-HADOOP-9902] yarn application help doesn't work

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1619604 | jlowe | 2014-08-21 23:38:16 +0200 (Thu, 21 Aug 2014) | 2 lines

HADOOP-10893. isolated classloader on the client side. Contributed by Sangjin Lee

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1619614 | jlowe | 2014-08-22 00:41:34 +0200 (Fri, 22 Aug 2014) | 2 lines

YARN-2434. RM should not recover containers from previously failed attempt when AM restart is not enabled. Contributed by Jian He

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1619626 | sandy | 2014-08-22 01:28:44 +0200 (Fri, 22 Aug 2014) | 1 line

MAPREDUCE-5130. Add missing job config options to mapred-default.xml (Ray Chiang via Sandy Ryza)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1619632 | aw | 2014-08-22 01:58:25 +0200 (Fri, 22 Aug 2014) | 1 line

HADOOP-8896. Javadoc points to Wrong Reader and Writer classes in SequenceFile (Ray Chiang via aw)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting `$log` and looking at it?

Comment: Yes, the example of svn log is the output of the $log variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn log` output can be redirect to some file and can be used for further extraction of useful information. PFB script to give logs of required day:-

```
#!/bin/bash

svn log > svn_logs_today.txt
printf "Enter the date in format YYYY-MM-DD for which revision no. to be displayed\n"
read var
#today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
#if required today variable can be used for extracting todays report
cat svn_logs_today.txt| grep $var
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case... It would be fine to print the results in a file and then top read the file (even if it would be more time consuming) but I need to write the data and revision in each line of the file, coming back to my previous problem of extracting those variables from the svn log ;-( 

This could be an example of file I need to save (or better of array) 

   1619604 2014-08-21
   1619614 2014-08-22
   1619626 2014-08-23 
   ...